# The cheapest and reliable way to unlock iphone 5?

Tags: iphone, unlock, cellular-carriers

What is the cheapest and reliable way to unlock iphone 5? Is there any reliable free solution?

The phone is now locked to U.S. Sprint service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reliable way is to get the carrier to unlock it. In the US - this means

- Verizon's are sold unlocked in the US whether you have a contract or not.
- AT&T's are locked, but they have a [process to get it unlocked](http://www.att.com/esupport/article.jsp?sid=KB414532) once your contract is fulfilled.
- Sprint's [situation is unclear](http://community.sprint.com/baw/thread/99365).
- T-Mobile's are [reported to be sold unlocked in 2013](http://gigaom.com/mobile/t-mobile-ceo-confirms-the-iphone-and-the-death-of-phone-subsidies/) when they start selling iPhone.

Cheapest depends heavily on your specific contract details and if you want to risk paying a third party to do something the cell carriers do not like. You could always look for a jailbreak and circumvent the lock, but between paying off your contract early or selling your locked phone and buying one that is legitimately unlocked is an easy, and simply about time and money now that unlocked iPhones are mainstream in the US. I suggest dealing locally in selling and buying an iPhone - connect on craigslist or wherever and meet in an Apple store so that you can check the serial number - be safe in a public space, etc...

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the phone is Sprint. So do you have any idea?

Comment: Like the linked article says - Sprint may not be unlocking any iPhones so if you can't get them to unlock it - sell the phone and buy one that is unlocked. You can usually get one within one year of purchase and buy AppleCare (or find one with AppleCare) so that you know the used phone has manufacturer warranty. Paying a third party to unlock a device is gray market / shadey at best so I wouldn't advise that unless it's your last option and you don't mind the hefty charge they will extract. Selling your phone is almost always cheaper than paying to get it unlocked.